# WP_Query not working with tax_query and woocommerce product attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to make ajax filter by attributes for woocommerce.
The problem is query giving empty result, when I'm adding `tax_query`. This code goes in functions.php

```
    $newquery = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
           'posts_per_page'        => '22',
           'post_status' => 'publish',
           'tax_query' => array( array(
               'taxonomy' => 'pa_chrisi', // Product attribute taxonomy: always start with 'pa_'
               'field'    => 'term_id', // Can be 'term_id', 'slug' or 'name'
               'terms'    => 170,
           ), ),
    
    ) );
```

I've checked the database for pa_chrisi taxonomy.
I've tried:

- to init woocommerce (not sure why) before my code.
- to add  `'suppress_filters' => true,` and `'include_children' => false,`

`echo $newquery->request;` gives me

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS dmg0j_posts.ID FROM dmg0j_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ( 0 = 1 ) AND dmg0j_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((dmg0j_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY dmg0j_posts.ID ORDER BY dmg0j_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 22`

If I remove `tax_query` part it works well. Im getting all products.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

solution:
if you are using **WP_Query** with **tax_query** in **functions.php** put the code inside an action with low priority:

```
add_action( 'init', 'maratgenius', 999 );
function maratgenius()
{
            $newquery = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type'             => 'product',
                   'posts_per_page'        => '-1',
                   'post_status' => 'publish',
                   'tax_query' => array( array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'pa_chrisi', // Product attribute taxonomy: always start with 'pa_'
                       'field'    => 'term_id', // Can be 'term_id', 'slug' or 'name'
                       'terms'    => $_POST['get_what'],
                   ), ),
            
            ) );
//other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can register WC taxonomies before query via:

```
\WC_Post_Types::register_taxonomies();
```